# React - Mocking user interaction for multiple forms

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run some tests in order to mock user interaction at my `react` frontend.

The following is my form component:

> **Form.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formData: {
        restaurant: '',
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    };
    this.handleUserFormSubmit = this.handleUserFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleFormChange = this.handleFormChange.bind(this);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.clearForm();
  };
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.formType !== nextProps.formType) {
      this.clearForm();
    };
  };
  clearForm() {
    this.setState({
      formData: {restaurant: '', username: '', email: '', password: ''}
    });
  };
  handleFormChange(event) {
    const obj = this.state.formData;
    obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
  };
  handleUserFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formType = this.props.formType
    const data = {
      restaurant: this.state.formData.restaurant,
      email: this.state.formData.email,
      password: this.state.formData.password
    };
    if (formType === 'register') {
      data.username = this.state.formData.username
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/auth/${formType}`;
    axios.post(url, data)
    .then((res) => {
      this.clearForm();
      this.props.loginUser(res.data.auth_token);
    })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
  };
  render() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to='/' />;
    };
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.formType === 'Login' &&
        <h1 className="title is-1">Log In</h1>
      }
      {this.props.formType === 'Register' &&
        <h1 className="title is-1">Register</h1>
      }
      <hr/><br/>
      <form onSubmit={(event) => this.props.handleUserFormSubmit(event)}>
       {this.props.formType === 'Register' &&
        <div className="field">
         <input
          name="restaurant"
          className="input is-medium"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your restaurant name"
          required
          value={this.state.formData.restaurant}
          onChange={this.props.handleFormChange}
        /> 
        </div>
        }
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="username"
              className="input is-medium"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter a username"
              required
              value={this.state.formData.username}
              onChange={this.props.handleFormChange}
            />
          </div>
        <div className="field">
          <input
            name="email"
            className="input is-medium"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter an email address"
            required
            value={this.state.formData.email}
            onChange={this.props.handleFormChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <input
            name="password"
            className="input is-medium"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter a password"
            required
            value={this.state.formData.password}
            onChange={this.props.handleFormChange}
          />
        </div>
        <input
          type="submit"
          className="button is-primary is-medium is-fullwidth"
          value="Submit"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
    )
  };
};

export default Form;
```

and this is the test:

> **Form.test.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, simulate } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { MemoryRouter, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Form from '../Form';

const testData = [
  {
    formType: 'Register',
    title: 'Register',
    formData: {
      restaurant:'',
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loginUser: jest.fn(),
    createMessage: jest.fn(),
    getUsers: jest.fn(),
  },
  {
    formType: 'Login',
    title: 'Log In',
    formData: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    },
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loginUser: jest.fn(),
    createMessage: jest.fn(),
    getUsers: jest.fn(),
  }
];

describe('When not authenticated', () => {
  testData.forEach((el) => {
    const component = <Form
      formType={el.formType}
      formData={el.formData}
      isAuthenticated={false}
    />;
    it(`${el.formType} Form renders properly`, () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(component);
      const h1 = wrapper.find('h1');
      expect(h1.length).toBe(1);
      expect(h1.get(0).props.children).toBe(el.title);
      const formGroup = wrapper.find('.field');
      expect(formGroup.length).toBe(Object.keys(el.formData).length);
      expect(formGroup.get(0).props.children.props.name).toBe(Object.keys(el.formData)[0]);
      expect(formGroup.get(0).props.children.props.value).toBe('');
    });
    it(`${el.formType} Form renders a snapshot properly`, () => {
      const tree = renderer.create(component).toJSON();
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  })
});
```

however, when I run it with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml exec client npm test -- --verbose
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/components/__tests__/Form.test.jsx
  When not authenticated
    ✓ Register Form renders properly (41ms)
    ✓ Register Form renders a snapshot properly (47ms)
    ✕ Login Form renders properly (38ms)
    ✓ Login Form renders a snapshot properly (9ms)

  ● When not authenticated › Login Form renders properly

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 3

      48 |       expect(h1.get(0).props.children).toBe(el.title);
      49 |       const formGroup = wrapper.find('.field');
    > 50 |       expect(formGroup.length).toBe(Object.keys(el.formData).length);
         |                                ^
      51 |       expect(formGroup.get(0).props.children.props.name).toBe(Object.keys(el.formData)[0]);
      52 |       expect(formGroup.get(0).props.children.props.value).toBe('');
      53 |     });

      at Object.toBe (src/components/__tests__/Form.test.jsx:50:32)
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add username to Login formData

```
  {
    formType: 'Login',
    title: 'Log In',
    formData: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      username: ''
    },
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loginUser: jest.fn(),
    createMessage: jest.fn(),
    getUsers: jest.fn(),
  }
```

Comment: it works, thanks. but `username` must be the first item for the tests to pass.